# "error_description":"AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'

Tags: java, azure

I used the code in https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/blob/master/src/samples/public-client-app-sample/src/main/java/PublicClient.java. The only difference is the CLIENT_ID is updated.

I keep getting the error message

> "error_description":"AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the
>   following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'

I am not sure how and where to specify this? Is there something that needs to be done in the configuration of the client by the admin?

Comment: You have to specify the client secret as well. That's what it is telling you.

Comment: @juunas: Yes. I agree. But my question is how or where should I specify this info. I do have the info but unable to use it.

Comment: @AnilShekhar The code sample you are referring to, acquires an access token from a Native app-registration. If your app-registration is of the type web-app, that code sample will not work as is and will throw AADSTS70002.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue and finally resolved. In my case I was using the **Redirect URI** (like a common web URL) copied from Web application section in dev console, which made the server "think" the request was from a web client. After changing to the **Redirect URI** (something in format of *urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob* , which means it's from a native client) from the application section, my Android app finally worked.

Comment: @ManuelHernandez   You can view from your Microsoft Portal web page (where you registered your web/mobile app) to learn your **Redirect URI** value.  Note that there're 2 portals: the old one for Azure portal and the new one for v2.0 (https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/).  What I mentioned above is for v2.0 portal.

Comment: Thanks bu I meant the format. All I see there is a standard fromat url in teh form of  www.contosos.com

Comment: On the old Azure portal page, you will always get a redirect URI in format of a domain name; If you're using new portal, you should see 2 sectors listed on that page with a domain-like one the **Web** app, and the other in format of "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" which is (automatically generated) for mobile app.  In my case, I used the former one in my Android app which resulted in the same error as mentioned by OP, and after I switched to use the later it worked fine.

Comment: If you already have a web application for your AAD App - On the new interface, you select the "App Platform" button, then select "Native Application"

Comment: The above comments weren't helping me find the format for the Native App's Redirect Uri. I eventually discovered it in the Documentation: 
"The redirect_uri of your app, where authentication responses can be sent and received by your app. It must exactly match one of the redirect_uris you registered in the portal, except it must be url encoded. For native & mobile apps, you should use the default value of urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-authorization-code